# Live USB Not Working (Black Screen before grub menu)

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have a very old XP machine I'm trying to install Ubuntu on (since XP has terminated security support).

I have a live USB key I'm trying to use as my setup CD and it is not working. It boots to a black screen with a flashing cursor.

There is no GRUB interface at the point it hangs; I get no Ubuntu splash screen, no options menu, nothing. Hitting <kbd>shift</kbd> does nothing, likewise hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>.

In my BIOS options there is no option for secure boot.

My computer is set up to boot from USB

I've used several different live USB/live CD programs to try and make a startup key including Universal USB installer and UNetbootin and nothing has changed.

I very little experience setting up a Linux system.

Comment: did you enable USB boot in the BIOS?

Comment: Some pc hardware is less compatible with Ubuntu installations, while others merely resist installation initially.  If you tell us the brand and model of your "xp machine" we will have a better chance at determining why you are having this difficulty.

Comment: Yes, USB boot is enabled

Comment: The computer I'm using is an old gateway computer with a 2.40GHz Pentium 4 processor and 1.50GB of RIMM Memory (2 x 256MB + 2 x 512MB)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever been able to boot from any USB on that computer? If not, then maybe it just doesn't like USB booting, or hates that particular USB device.

I'd try a cd/dvd/dvd-rw disk, should definitely work for any computer that can run WinXP.

But if your computer is really that old, the regular Ubuntu might be too slow, may want to look into [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), or a ubuntu-derived distro that's "lighter", or even Debian-based [CrunchBang](http://crunchbang.org/) (that uses the Openbox WM). See http://distrowatch.com/ to search.

---

- Just thought it ***could*** be your **old computer is only 32-bit**, and if you're trying a 64-bit Ubuntu (or any 64-bit OS) it won't be able to boot either...

According to [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/products/27438/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-2_40-GHz-512K-Cache-533-MHz-FSB) for "Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor 2.40 GHz, 512K Cache, 533 MHz FSB" (could be yours from your comment) it's "Instruction Set" is **32-bit**, so you should use 32-bit OS's. I [think it](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Pentium_4/Intel-Mobile%20Pentium%204%202.4%20GHz%20-%20RK80532GE056512.html) supports [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) so should be ok even if have >4GB ram, and some distros require PAE support too (Linux Mint & Ubuntu?).

(32-bit seems to use less RAM anyway, and only a little bit slower, I prefer it)

Comment: I was actually worried about that and was unsure of which distro to use if Ubuntu was unable to be run. I can set the USB stick to boot to DOS and it seems to work fine. I have some DVD's ordered and I'm hoping you guys are right and that's the source of my problem. If not I'll look into versions you mentioned above; thank you very much for the info.

Comment: @JosephBourque Just had a thought about your computer not being able to boot any 64-bit OS, not sure which version of Ubuntu you're trying, I think they recommend the 64-bit version now, you might need 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you attempting to create the Live USB in?  Would I be right in guessing WinXP?

I had similar issues and used LiveUSB Creator within Windows.  Here's a link:

https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/

If you are using a Linux system while creating the live usb, give mintstick (from the Linux Mint repositories):  Here is a link for the respositories:

http://www.packages.linuxmint.com/

These are all .deb packages and are easily installable on Ubuntu/Debian based distros.  If you are using Linux I would think that picking the Linux 13 page and scrolling down until to "mintstick" would work.

Lastly, there have been some instances where I have tried to do installs on older boxes and found that by using a liveDVD or liveCD rather than a usb stick worked.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I'm actually using a windows machine to create the key as I won't have access to a Linux machine until the 20th

So far as the CD track; I have not tried that yet as I don't have any DVD's handy at the moment but will pick up some and try next time I have the chance. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I have it! ... or at least I've experienced this.  If I'm correct the difficulty you are having isn't actually a boot issue but a problem Ubuntu brought about for certain Gateway laptops after version 9.10 or so.  One version upgrade and bam, black screen at boot time, but I found a work around.

Next time you try to boot and the screen goes black press ctrl-alt-F1 and then ctrl-alt-F7.  Something about putting it in terminal mode and pulling it back out caused my graphics to return.  I had to do this for more than a year before I realized that as much as I loved that laptop, it was just too annoying.  I preferred to explain to friends that it was an extra level of security in so much as nobody could log into my laptop if they couldn't even see the login screen.